# MAP Director for ArcGIS

Tags: arcmap, arcgis-10.1, arcgis-desktop

I have installed the Cartegraph 8, where I would like to know if it is possible to add the MAPDirector for ArcGIS Extension to ArcMap.

As per the following documentation, it seems like the extension should be available from the Customize > Extensions > Map Director for ArcGIS. Unfortunately I was not able to get the extension displayed in ArcMap.

Cartegraph Documentation:
http://ua.cartegraph.com/ua/Content/MapSolutions/MapArc/ArcMapExtension_Task.htm

I could also find the following ESRI link, however I was not able to get the how to steps to add this extension to ArcMap.

ESRI Documentation:
http://www.esri.com/news/arcnews/spring03articles/business-partners.html

I am suspecting if this is something to do with the registration of the DLL. However when I went to the C:\ProgramFiles (x86)\Cartegraph\, I could only see a system folder, where I can see many folders such as bin, Utils, etc. However I am not sure which DLL that I would need to register to make the extension available in ArcGIS.

ArcGIS Version: 10.1
Cartegraph Version: 8
OS: Win 7 64-bit

Please suggest me on this issue.